# Difference between true and True?

Tags: apex

What is the difference between

```
@InvocableVariable(required=true)
```

and

```
@InvocableVariable(required=True)
```

Are these two the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A capital **T** ... Apex is not case sensitive